# MySql timestamp query and comparison in monthly and weekly

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, regex

i have a table where i enter entries for applicants. it has a column date_added where the type is timestamp and the default is current_timestamp. i want to make a weekly and monthly report but i can't decide what would be the best thing to do. i need an sql statement that return the number of entry like this..

```
switch($searchby){
case "monthly": $qry = "select * from tblapplicant where date_added > $month"; break;
case "weekly": $qry = "select * from tblapplicant where date_added > $week"; break;
}

$res = mysql_query($select);
$rec_count = mysql_num_rows($res);

echo "There are <font color='red' size='3'>".$rec_count."</font> matching records found.";
```

i know this is incorrect but this is all i can think at the moment.

another thing i want is, i want it to be the exact year and month report..

edit:
output should be:
There are 13 applicants for the whole month of June 2013. - or if weekly - 
There are 3 applicants for the third quarter of July 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approach.  First, use your php code to determine the day that your search period begins, and the day after it ends.  For example, if it's a monthtly report for September 2013, your start date would be 2013-09-01, and the end date would be 2013-10-01.  Then you simply have one query.

```
 where date_added >= $startdate
 and date_added < $enddate
```

The major benefits of this approach are:

1. The time component of your timestamp field gets handled.
2. Your query will run reasonably quickly, especially if date_added is indexed.
3. It's easier to sort out programmnig logic with application code than with sql
4. You can write your query as a stored procedure to make it even faster.

Comment: i understand. thanks for explaining it thoroughly.. how about for weekly?

Comment: You already have your php code started with your switch statement.  What you are doing for each case is setting two variables, one for the start date and one for the end date.

Comment: do you think that adding 7 days for each week in the statement is ok?

Comment: It's hard to say because your question is not as clear as it could be.  Perhaps if you edited it and showed the query output you are trying to achieve, I or someone else could give a better answer.

Comment: this statement doesn't return anything select * from tblapplicant where date(date_added) >= 2013-09-01 and date(date_added) < 2013-11-01;

but if i remove the end date, it'll return entries that are added after the date start

Comment: If you remove the end date and look at the data, do any of them have a date added earlier than 2013-11-01?

Answer (score 0):

This can be your sql statement

```
select * from tblapplicant where month(date_added) > $month
select * from tblapplicant where DAYOFWEEK(date_added) = X
```

You should replace X whith your weeek day 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday

Comment: Functions in the where clause like that tend to slow down production.